# Make a "callback" between page and popup

Tags: c#, xamarin, callback

I want to know how can I make a "callback" (I don't know if callback is the true word) for my popup.
[image]

In fact, when I click on my button Continue in my MainPage, open my Popup and get the button value when I click on at.

For example, No return False, and Yes return true.

After that, my popup will close, and I know if I can continue or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a MessagingCenter. For Example, your Firs Page can Subscribe a MessagingCenter in it's OnAppearing (and unsubscribe in OnDisappearing... you should test this because I don't know if there are problems when your PopupPage "popups").

This Subscribe can receive a boolean Args

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyPopupPage, bool>(this, "ReturnFromPopup", (sender, arg) =>{


    if(arg){
        // Do something for true
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something for FALSE
    }

})
```

Your Popup should have something like

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<MyPopupPage, bool>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ReturnFromPopup", true); // If press yes, otherwise false
```